# Download Captions Using Youtube API

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to download captions for youtube videos using the youtube api.  However, I am not sure how to implement this.  The example implementation on the google api [youtube api page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download#parameters) has example implementations in java, python, and php, but not swift.  How can i implement this in swift.  Thank you.

I have only implemented how to retreive the general JSON for details about the video.  However, according to the Youtube api it should be posisble to download the captions.  If i can't download them, how can I retrieve the captions?

```
    // Set up your URL
    let youtubeApi = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2C+snippet%2C+statistics&id=dNV7COWz8ME&key=AIzaSyCuBFAb9dJIhK3LH0d4f5yoq5skfDdIC4w"
    let url = NSURL(string: youtubeApi)

    // Create your request
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {

                print("Response from YouTube: \(jsonResult)")
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }

    })

    // Start the request
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried?

Comment: You are seeking complete implementation? Did You try to code something yet?

Comment: edited to show my current progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading captions takes three steps:

- get the caption(s) ID
- get the caption(s) list
- get the data for the caption(s)

First, download the *captions ID* and the *captions list* for the video using this URL:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=xxx&key=yyy

and parse the response (we'll see how in my example).

Then, get the *captions data* using this URL:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?id=xxx&tfmt=yyy

where `xxx` is the ID we just got and `yyy` is the format you want for the captions, for example "srt".

It will return the captions as data.

Example using your video:

```
let youtubeApi = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=dNV7COWz8ME&key=AIzaSyCuBFAb9dJIhK3LH0d4f5yoq5skfDdIC4w"
if let url = NSURL(string: youtubeApi) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let data = data, jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? [[String : AnyObject]],
                    item = items.first,
                    id = item["id"] {
                    print(id)
                    if let captionsURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?id=\(id)&tfmt=srt") {
                        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(captionsURL, completionHandler: { (cdata, cresponse, cerror) in
                            if let captionsResponse = cresponse {
                                print(captionsResponse)
                            }
                            if let captionsData = cdata {
                                print(captionsData)
                            }
                        }).resume()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Also note that in this example I only take the first caption from the list of captions (`items.first`) but there may be more for some videos.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download says that you need to authorize. This is missing here.